# ios 13.6 simulator not lauching expo

Tags: ios, xcode, expo, ios-simulator

I want to test my expo app on old version of ios, namely `ios 13.6` or `ios 13.7`. Expo works well on `ios version >= 14.0`. However, when I try to launch expo on `ios 13.6` or `ios 13.7`, the app loads for one second (I see  white screen) then is being killed.
Here is the system log when I try to launch expo:

> Jan 14 11:43:19 MacBook-Pro-de-Gilles com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.6D290037-CCB6-46A9-9590-C47D7B34D98E[2020] (UIKitApplication:host.exp.Exponent[e203][rb-legacy][2287]): Service exited due to SIGILL | sent by exc handler[2287]

I have got the same behavior when I try to launch Safari or Photos. The system logs display these two messages every 10 seconds (even when I don't try to launch Safari):

> Jan 14 11:43:14 MacBook-Pro-de-Gilles com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.6D290037-CCB6-46A9-9590-C47D7B34D98E[2020] (com.apple.SafariBookmarksSyncAgent[2257]): Service exited due to SIGTRAP | sent by exc handler[2257]
> Jan 14 11:43:14 MacBook-Pro-de-Gilles com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.6D290037-CCB6-46A9-9590-C47D7B34D98E[2020] (com.apple.SafariBookmarksSyncAgent): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.

I don't care about using safari, I just care about expo. I have shown these errors because these issues might be related.

I use expo sdk 40 and mac os big sur on a mac book pro with apple chip.

Thanks for helping!